# "This interaction failed" : discord.py Button

Tags: python, discord.py

so currently I try to program a calculator but I hit a roadblock. Well, I watched a tutorial by Glowstik on how to make calculator discord bot but it seems that his code doesn't work anymore. So, can anybody suggest changes that I can make to the code to make the bot work? Thanks in advance.
Here is the code :

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from online import keep_alive
from discord_slash import SlashCommand
from itertools import cycle
from discord_components import *
import datetime

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

slash = SlashCommand(client, sync_commands=True)

status = cycle([
    " Unanswered Question of Life", " Self - Referential Paradox",
    " Near-infinite density?", " Dark matter ?",
    " Measurement of the speed of light in one straight line",
    " Schrodinger's cat ???",
    "The light side of Discord is the path of many unnatural abilities"
])


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("I have logged in as {0.user}".format(client))
    status_swap.start()
    DiscordComponents(client)


buttons = [[
    Button(style=ButtonStyle.grey, label='1'),
    Button(style=ButtonStyle.grey, label='2'),
    Button(style=ButtonStyle.grey, label='3'),
    Button(style=ButtonStyle.blue, label='+'),
    Button(style=ButtonStyle.red, label='Clear')
],
[
    Button(style=ButtonStyle.grey, label='4'),
    Button(style=ButtonStyle.grey, label='5'),
    Button(style=ButtonStyle.grey, label='6'),
    Button(style=ButtonStyle.blue, label='-'),
    Button(style=ButtonStyle.red, label='Exit')
],
[
    Button(style=ButtonStyle.grey, label='7'),
    Button(style=ButtonStyle.grey, label='8'),
    Button(style=ButtonStyle.grey, label='9'),
    Button(style=ButtonStyle.blue, label='×'),
    Button(style=ButtonStyle.red, label='←')
],
[
    Button(style=ButtonStyle.grey, label='00'),
    Button(style=ButtonStyle.grey, label='0'),
    Button(style=ButtonStyle.grey, label='.'),
    Button(style=ButtonStyle.blue, label='÷'),
    Button(style=ButtonStyle.red, label='=')
]]


def calculator(exp):
  o = exp.replace('×', '*')
  o = o.replace('÷', '/')
  result = " "
  try:
    result = str(eval(o))
  except:
    result = "An error occurs"
  return result


@client.command()
async def operator(ctx):
  m = await ctx.send(content="Loading calculator")
  expression = "None"
  delta = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes = 5)
  e = discord.Embed(title="Basic Operation Calculator",description=expression)
  await m.edit(components=buttons, embed=e)
  while True :
    res = await client.wait_for("button click")
  while m.created_at < delta :
    if res.author.id == int(res.message.embeds[0].title.split("|")[1]) and res.message.embeds[0].timestamp < delta:
      expression = res.message.embeds[0].description
      if expression == "None" or expression == 'An error occurs':
        expression = ''
      elif res.component.label == 'Exit':
        await res.respond(content='Calculator Closed. Thanks for using Basic Operation Calculator.',type=7)
        break
      elif res.component.label == "←":
        expression = expression[:-1]
      elif res.component.label == 'Clear':
        expression = None
      elif res.component.label == '=':
        expression += calculator(expression)
      else:
        expression = res.component.label
      f = discord.Embed(title='Basic Operation Calculator',description=expression)
      await res.respond(content='', embed = f, component=buttons, type=7)

@ tasks.loop(minutes=5)
async def status_swap():
  await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(next(status)))


keep_alive()
client.run(os.getenv('MATH_VAR'))
```

Comment: Remember that stackoverflow's community mustn't spoonfeed contributors. You have to ask us something more precise, like how to fix an error, or how to create a simple command. Nobody will read more than 100 lines of code...

Answer (score 1):

This code looks like it was taken from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3BGcgSm9sv0
which coincidentally I have also used.

Your problem arises from your embed title because it's based around your title having a '|' followed by the user's ID.
try changing the embed title from `"Basic Operation Calculator"` to `f"{ctx.message.author}'s calculator|{ctx.message.author.id}"` and tell me if that works. I've modified the code I'm using slightly, so this might be wrong, I'm going off of memory here. If that does work, also try `f"Basic Operation Calculator|{ctx.message.author.id}"` if you want to keep your title name.

This isn't needed but if you also want to add a sliver of text after the '|', you need to change the split statement in
`if res.author.id == int(res.message.embeds[0].title.split("|")[1]) and res.message.embeds[0].timestamp < delta:`

to the '|' and any text (thats not the ID) directly after.
so if I want to add "ID: " after, then the split statement would be "| ID: ". Sorry if this sounds confusing, the way this code works is very specific, and I'm pretty new to Stack Overflow. Let me know if you run into any errors or have any questions. If nothing else works I'm happy to send you my current code I'm using since It's only slightly modified. Next time you post a question, try your best to be as specific as possible with your question.